# Share resource between multiple pthread, POCO thread and boost thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, pthreads, poco

I am working on project which requires merging of two additional project. Now I have three projects that has threads created using pthread, POC::Thread and Boost::Thread respectively.

I am having a hard time deciding how to provide access of shared resource to POCO and Boost threads. I am planning to use boost's shared_mutex to access global map.

I am worried about the future implications.
My query:
Is it possible to protect shared resource (here c++ map) between pthread, poco thread and boost thread using boost's shared_mutex?

Comment: Have you considered using The Standard Library for the mutex?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex

Comment: Ok. I can use standard lib's mutex. But is it possible to protect a global resource that will be accessed by all pthread, poco and boost threads? Will it affect compatibility?

Comment: Under-the-hood all of the above will be using the native OS thread and synchronisation primitives.